# MATLAB imageInputLayer vs sequenceInputLayer

Tags: neural-networks, matlab

I have two networks:

```
 layers = [ ...
sequenceInputLayer(250)
fullyConnectedLayer(100)
fullyConnectedLayer(1)
regressionLayer];
```

and

```
layers = [ ...
imageInputLayer([250 1])
fullyConnectedLayer(100)
fullyConnectedLayer(1)
regressionLayer];
```

My intuition tells me that these should essentially be the same network, but I get significantly better results with the latter. One difference between `imageInputLayer` and `sequenceInputLayer` is that the former has zerocenter on by default. But even when I set the options to  `imageInputLayer([250 1],'Normalization','none')` I still get better performance than with the `sequenceInputLayer`. In fact, with the same IRL the `sequenceInputLayer` diverges for some training runs whereas the `imageInputLayer` has never has this problem. Why is this happening?